# How to set Eclipse character encoding in version control?

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding, collaboration

We have an Eclipse project with several developers. The default character encoding differs between machines. How can I configure Eclipse to use a specific character encoding, so that the setting persists between machines with **no manual intervention needed**?

Comment: We're using Gradle, and there is a plugin for generating classpaths and whatnot, but there's no hook in the plugin for setting the character encoding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16294353/1700321.

Comment: This is not about setting the character encoding for reading in Gradle, it's *specifically* about setting the encoding *in Eclipse* so that *Eclipse* doesn't *write* text files in an unwanted encoding.

Comment: I followed a link to the documentation for Gradle's `CompileOptions`, which seems to have been deleted now. The StackOverflow link wasn't on my screen when I wrote my last comment. That is indeed a legitimate duplicate candidate, although my question is build system agnostic while the linked question is not.

Comment: It is build system vs ide. Different people can use different ide-s for the same project, but different build systems is rarely used for the same project.

Answer (score 1):

When you [configure this in the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9181055/833844), Eclipse stores this setting at `.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs`. You can simply commit that file to version control:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
encoding/<project>=UTF-8
```